# Cocos2d 2.1 - How can I show UIImagePicker view controller from within CCLayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I a using Cocos2d 2.1. Latest stable. I've read some other posts related to this question but I suspect that they may be using older versions of Cocos2d. I have a MenuLayer (CCLayer) and I would like to present the UIImagePicker view. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
-(void)pickPhoto{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:picker.view];
```

}

The application crashes with the following error:

> -[MenuLayer presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89768f0

So CCLayer must not be a UIViewController. Can someone tell how to correctly show the UIImagePicker from within a CCLayer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have it figured out.

This solution works:

```
-(void)pickPhoto{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:picker.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The presentModalViewController is a method from UIViewController. You can call this method only the class which inherited from UIViewController. However in your case MenuLayer is not inherited from UIViewController. If you want to present view controller you should use CDDirector class.

```
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```